# Проблема с закрытием файла

Tags: python, файлы

Есть простенький код:

```
source = open('num1.txt')
rest = open('result.txt','a')
for s in source:
    l = []    
    if int(s) % 2 == 0:
        l.append(int(s))
rest.write('min={}\nmax={}'.format(str(min(l)), str(max(l))))
source.close()
rest.close()
```

Без последних двух строк код выполняется корректно. Но с ними выскакивает ошибка:
`source.close() syntax error`, а если строку удалить, то `rest.close() syntax error`. 
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Вы отладку вообще-то делали?  Или сразу на форум? Что будет в вашей программе если цикл и строку write закомментировать?

Comment: Не должно быть такого, странно это

Comment: Я попробовал, у меня так не ругается. Что-то у вас не совсем так на самом деле, как тут в листинге представлено.

Comment: @CrazyElf -  да код-то подправленный. Предполагаю, что там, в оригинале,  или с отступами что-то не так, или где-то символ какой затесался или пропал, который подправили при исправлении кода. А отладки элементарной наш ТС скорее всего не делал.

Comment: @passant Если бы с отступами, то на отступы бы и ругалось, наверное. Хотя может зависит от среды исполнения. Скорее всё же какие-то левые символы, да )

Comment: @passant ну, конечно, выполнил. Код не был подправлен. Перезапустил его в PyCharm и он почему-то заработал, а VSCode тупил, пришлось переписать его. Опыт путь ошибок. Всем спасибо за замечания!